# ASP.NET MVC 4 RouteLink not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 Application, I used Area and this is my route:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Service_AcceptBid",
                "Service/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{accept}",
                new { area = "Service", controller = "Project", action = "AcceptBid", id = UrlParameter.Optional, accept = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

context.MapRoute(
                "Service_BidNegotiation",
                "Service/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{bid}",
                new { area = "Service", controller = "Project", action = "Negotiations", id = UrlParameter.Optional, bid = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I put these links on my .cshtml page:

```
<div dir="ltr">
       @Html.RouteLink("Accept", "Service_AcceptBid", new { controller = "Project", action = "AcceptBid", Id = item.ProjectId, Accept = item.Id })
       @Html.RouteLink("Negotiate", "Service_BidNegotiation", new { controller = "Project", action = "Negotiations", Id = item.ProjectId, Bid = item.Id })
</div>
```

When first link clicked, `AcceptBid` controller called and it's parameters (Id, Accept) are set to url value. but when I clicked on second link, Id parameter in controller method has set but second parametere (Bid) is null.

Why this happen ?
What can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: No, lower and uppercase are same. Lowercase not working too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explaining the problem

Output routing (link generation) was fine. The problem is with incoming routing. When you click the second link that should be handled by the first route it actually gets handled by the first route, because it matches its definition.

### Possible solution (without hardcoding actions)

All you have to do is to provide additional constraints to the first route that will prevent it to handle requests that should be handled by the second route.

Check my following code change where I added route constraints on the `action` parameter to provide possible values:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Service_AcceptBid",
    "Service/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{accept}",
    new { area = "Service", controller = "Project", action = "AcceptBid", id = UrlParameter.Optional, accept = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { action = "AcceptBid|RejectBid|..." }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Service_BidNegotiation",
    "Service/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{bid}",
    new { area = "Service", controller = "Project", action = "Negotiations", id = UrlParameter.Optional, bid = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This will keep your routes more dynamic than creating static route definitions for each individual action.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) it's a best way to avoid hard-coding. It's nicely worked.

Answer (score 2):

The `{action}` pattern is ambiguous.

To work around this, hard-code the specific route.

Example:

```
"Service/{controller}/AcceptBid/{id}/{accept}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed this route to hard-code and it's working. But why I can't do this without hard-code ?

Comment: @Mojtaba: Your link was created as expected, but when you clicked it, it got handled by the first route, that doesn't define `Bid` parameter but rather `accept`. You could get away with non-hardcoded route, but it would require some constraints on it, so that it wouldn't catch incoming requests that should be handled by the second route.